# Clean Laravel To Bake New Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

I just did a fresh install of Laravel v5.5.25. I want to create a brand new project so I want to clear out some files in Laravel. For example, I want to delete all readymade templates (welcome page too), delete bootstrap from Laravel, etc. I just want to do ultimate start. So, will you please guide me what else should I delete too to make it a skeleton? And please tell me how can I remove bootstrap completely and replace it with Bulma.

Comment: There is no twitter bootstrap bundled with the Laravel project. What you are seeing named as bootstrap is generally the term used for an application to launch itself up.

Comment: In resources/assets/js/app.js there is `require('./bootstrap');`

Comment: And while compiling app.js why it is more than 1MB?

Comment: @Sanjay - Yes but as Mehrdad Dastgir said, that is the "bootstrapper", not Bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can run:

```
php artisan preset none
```

to remove default preset.

There is no Bulma preset of of the box, available options are:

- none
- bootstrap
- vue
- react

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel Presets](https://laravel-news.com/frontend-presets) for that. If you want a “skeleton” as you said you should use `php artisan preset none`. There is [also one for Bulma](https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/bulma): `composer require laravel-frontend-presets/bulma` and then `php artisan preset bulma`.